# Let G be a group, and $N\triangleleft G$. Then, the quotient map $q: G\rightarrow G/N$ given by $q(g) = g\circ N$ is an epimorphism.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

**My attempt:**

1. Showing that the given map is a homomorphism.
   Let $a, b ∈ G$
   Then, $q(a\circ b) = (a\circ b)\circ N = (a\circ N)\circ(b\circ N) = q(a)\circ q(b)$.
2. Showing surjectivity [I am stuck up here...]

Comment: What's the def of $G/N$ you use?

Comment: The definition I am using is: (Quotient Group) G/N is the group of all left cosets of N in G. @coffeemath

Comment: Then if a left coset is $a \circ N$ the map is clearly surjective, you already checked homomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick an element (coset) $g N \in G/N$. Then just use $g \in G$ (the coset representative) and $g \mapsto g N$ to give us surjectivity.

---

Also, I presume you are using epimorphism and surjection interchangeably in the setting of groups, but just for completeness, in the category of groups, we have that a morphism is a surjection if and only if it is an epimorphism, so the fact that this is a surjection shows that it is an epimorphism in $\mathsf{Grp}$.

Comment: I am using: Epimorphism = Surjective homomorphism. Is anything wrong in this?

Comment: No nothing to worry about because in the category of groups, the two notions are the same. They are not the same in other categories however!

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $a,b \in G$. Then $$q(ab)=abN=(aN)(bN)=q(a)q(b).$$ That is, $q$ is a group homomorphism.

(Since $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$,$(aN)(bN)=abN$ multiplication is well-defined.

Because let $x\in(aN)(bN)$. Then $x=an_1 bn_2$ for some $n_1 , n_2 \in N$

Since $N$ is normal, $gN=Ng$ for all $g\in G$. Then  $x=an_1 bn_2=a(n_1 b)n_2 =a(b {n'}_1)n_2 =ab{n'}_1 n_2 \in abN$.

Conversely, choosing $a\in aN$ and $b \in bN$, we obtain the coset $abN$.)

2. Let $\bar g \in G/N$. Then $\bar g = gN$ for some $g\in G$. We choose $g$. Then $q(g)=\bar g=gN$